# MessageWebSocket MessageReiceived Parsing C#

Tags: c#

So i'm looking for a good way to parse my web socket message text.

```
["XdHAIAWqnCIEOHZ00", 2555195586415, 3, 1577655354100, "XTyatACqnA2YMv2x0", "XTyatACqnA2YMv2x0"]
```

as of now i'm just using string.Split and manually pulling what i need but i was wondering if there was a way to have it come out looking like.

```
["XW2clACqnA94btL70", 2555266357205, 13, 1577964035000, {Type: 10, Data: "AAAAAAUAAAAAAAAJ0"},…]

0: "XW2clACqnA94btL70"
1: 2555196057105
2: 13
3: 1577664031000
4: {Type: 10, Data: "AAAAAAUAAAAAAAAJ0"}
    Type: 10
    Data: "AAAAAAUAAAAAAAAJ0"
5: "XW2clACqnA94btL70"
```

and also an explanation on what the unquoted tokens are: `2555266357205, 13, 1577964035000`

Where they come from and what they're used for?